# Suggestion on how to build a Node js book assignment application?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, swagger-node-express

I have used little Node js/Node express and would like to discuss to you all of the proposed project I am working on. I am working on an application where users can add, remove and modify books (they have a title, category, an intended due date and completion date to be done by). This is a very broad question I know but do any of you know any tutorial, downloadable code that you think could be useful? Or any topics in node I should look at? Sorry as I have not used Node and would like to ask you some experts on this software before carrying out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb will help you build a simple NodeJs app that can do what you want